# How to connect to mongodb via mongoose in nodejs

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

controller/product.controller.js this is the controller class

```
const Product = require('../models/product.model');

//Simple version, without validation or sanitation
exports.test = function (req, res) {
    res.send('Greetings from the Test controller!');
};

exports.product_create = function (req, res) {
    const product = new Product(
        {
            name: req.body.name,
            price: req.body.price
        }
    );

    product.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.send('Product Created successfully')
    })
};
```

models/product.model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, max: 100},
    price: {type: Number, required: true},
});


exports.product_details = function (req, res) {
    Product.findById(req.params.id, function (err, product) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(product);
    })
};
exports.product_delete = function (req, res) {
    Product.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function (err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send('Deleted successfully!');
    })
};

exports.product_update = function (req, res) {
    Product.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: req.body}, function (err, product) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send('Product udpated.');
    });
};
router.put('/:id/update', product_controller.product_update);


// Export the model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema);
```

product.route.js this is used to route

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Require the controllers WHICH WE DID NOT CREATE YET!!
const product_controller = require('../controllers/product.controller');
router.post('/create', product_controller.product_create);


// a simple test url to check that all of our files are communicating correctly.
router.get('/test', product_controller.test);
router.put('/:id/update', product_controller.product_update);
router.delete('/:id/delete', product_controller.product_delete);

module.exports = router;
```

app.js this is the app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const product = require('./routes/product.route'); // Imports routes for the products
const app = express();


// Set up mongoose connection on mongoAtlas
//https://codeburst.io/writing-a-crud-app-with-node-js-and-mongodb-e0827cbbdafb
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dev_db_url = 'mongodb://someuser:abcd1234@ds123619.mlab.com:23619/productstutorial';
const mongoDB = process.env.MONGODB_URI || dev_db_url;
mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

app.use('/products', product);


app.listen(3000,function () {
    console.log("Server listen on port: 3000");

});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use('/products', product);
```

So this is the code of the project and please add scripts     "start": "node app.js". This will directly be able to use this and update,insert and delete data is also given here with the code.

Comment: Hello @pasan, So the question is you were getting issues with connecting mongodb, can you also share the error trace, people would know better when they will see the error trace.

Answer (score 1):

The setup looks good, However I noticed few points you might missed in app.js. I believe the following slightly modified setup will connect your mongodb properly:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const product = require('./routes/product.route'); // Imports routes for the products

const API_PORT = 3000;
const app = express();

app.use(cors());


// Set up mongoose connection on mongoAtlas
//https://codeburst.io/writing-a-crud-app-with-node-js-and-mongodb-e0827cbbdafb
const dev_db_url = 'mongodb://someuser:abcd1234@ds123619.mlab.com:23619/productstutorial';

// connects our back end code with the database
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || dev_db_url, { useNewUrlParser: true });

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open', () => console.log('connected to the database'));

// checks if connection with the database is successful
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));

// bodyParser, parses the request body to be a readable json format
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// append /api for our http requests
app.use('/product', product);

// launch our backend into a port
app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`LISTENING ON PORT ${API_PORT}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoose.connect(url, (err) => {
    if (!err) {
        app.listen(PORT, () => {
            console.log('SERVER WORKING');
        })
    }
})
```